# Creating a DataTable from a Linq query from a model passed in

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I am trying to take a Linq query and populate a datatable.  After a day of trying various methods I have something that will compile but my issue is that the CopyToDataTable is giving a null exception.

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> cancellations = cl.AsEnumerable() as IEnumerable<DataRow>;

Trace.WriteLine(cancellations);

DataTable datatable = cancellations.CopyToDataTable<DataRow>();
```

In Intellitrace, if I hover over cancellations it states Null and the Trace confirms that, over cl it has one record as expected as well as one record if I look at the entry of the method.

Am I missing something simple having stared at it all day?

```
public class CancellationList
{
    public int SchemeId { get; set; }
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: What is `cl`? And try remove `as IEnumerable<DataRow>`.

Comment: cl is a List<CancellationList> cl = new List<CancellationList>();  If you remove the as IEnumerable<DataRow> you then get a cast exception as I taking a list to a datarow (for the datatable).  I must have tried about 10 different ways today on this but this is the closest I have got.

Comment: CopyToDataTable only takes DataRow so unless CancellationList is also inherits from DataRow the As cast will return back null.  Can you give us the CancellationList class

Comment: It's possible to create DataTable using Linq to Dataset look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386921(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Charles, added in model.  Its a very straightforward class.  What you said now explains the behavior.  Martijn, looked at this earlier but it loads the dataset first and I didn't understand that.  The latter part is almost what I have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't going to be a built in way to do this.  You will need to code it.  If you just want it to work with CancellationList you can do this

```
var cl = new List<CancellationList>();
var dataTable = new DataTable();
var toObject = cl.Select(c => new object[] {c.SchemeId, c.EffectiveDate, c.TransactionDate, c.ExpiryDate});
dataTable.Columns.Add("SchemeId", typeof (int));
dataTable.Columns.Add("EffectiveDate", typeof (DateTime));
dataTable.Columns.Add("TransactionDate", typeof(DateTime));
dataTable.Columns.Add("ExpiryDate", typeof(DateTime));
foreach (var data in toObject)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to follow the instructions in this MSDN article: [How to: Implement CopyToDataTable Where the Generic Type T Is Not a DataRow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669096%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

It's very straightforward:

1. Copy the `ObjectShredder<T>` source code in the article and place it in its own file since it's a class. It's a lot of code, but it'll save you from manually needing to construct the DataTable.
2. Add the `CustomLINQtoDataSetMethods` class from the article, which wraps the `ObjectShredder` in a nice extension method named `CopyToDataTable`.
3. Next, use `CopyToDataTable` over an `IEnumerable<T>`.

With all those items in place, you'll be able to use it as follows:

```
DataTable table = cl.CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Thanks Ahmad, I picked up on Charles solution first and works a treat so have selected it.  Thanks #Charles, would have never got there on my own.